# How to get sound working through HDMI with Intel HD Audio in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: sound, hdmi, 13.04, hda-intel

HDMI output used to work fine on my Samsung NP300E5C laptop in Ubuntu 12.04. However, I did a reinstall with the new 13.04 release (64 bit), and now I don't see the HDMI output as a choice in the Sound Settings.

The `aplay -l` command returns the following:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC269VC Analog [ALC269VC Analog]
      Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

This means that the device is found, but can't be used, as can be seen when I input `speaker-test -c 2 -r 48000 -D hw:0,3`:

```
speaker-test 1.0.25

Playback device is hw:0,3
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 2 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
Playback open error: -19,No such device
```

Also, `alsamixer` doesn't show sliders related to the HDMI output. What do?

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge there is a bug in the 3.9.0-19-generic kernel that causes this, you can use the mainline kernel till it is fixed, here is a easy installer for it https://github.com/GM-Script-Writer-62850/Ubuntu-Mainline-Kernel-Updater

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH... I've spent 2 hours trying to fix this with no success... After finding this question and reading your answer IT WORKED.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a kernel bug introduced around mid-April (by ubuntu I think). 
Generic kernels don't have the problem. Nor do ubuntu kernels before mid April.

subscribe to this bug report to keep up to date on it:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1169761

Comment: Thanks to both answerers. Now we can see the latest episode of the most popular soap opera of my country with my girlfriend without me having to boot into w*ndows, accompanied by a lot swearing on my part. I'll keep following the bug report, hope the ubuntu kernels catch up!

Answer (score 0):

After not having success with adding the alsa-daily packages or options to alsa-base.conf, I found if I added radeon.audio=1 to my boot options I was able to get audio to work. Still need to perform more testing to see how stable it is.

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=124130

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

replace

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

with

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i915.disable_power_well=0 quiet splash"
```

from: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1256655

Comment: Better to run `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` to prevent [hassles with user-specific gedit config files](http://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-user-should-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-application).